# Why using LeetCode 138 get error: cannot find symbol: variable get?

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is my code:

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list with a random pointer.
* class RandomListNode {
*     int label;
*     RandomListNode next, random;
*     RandomListNode(int x) { this.label = x; }
* };
*/


  public class Solution {
        public RandomListNode copyRandomList(RandomListNode head) {
            //using a map to store the number and Node
            HashMap<RandomListNode,Integer>old_Node=new  HashMap<>(); 
            // using a list to store the Node
            LinkedList<RandomListNode> new_Node = new LinkedList<>(); 
            // store the First_Head
            RandomListNode first_head= head;
```

to init all thing

```
  int i =0;
        while(head!=null){
            //add everynode ,and number to map
            old_Node.put(head.random,i);    
            //add everynode to list
            new_Node.add(new RandomListNode(head.label));

            head=head.next;
            i++;
        }
```

to copy the RandomNode

```
  head=first_head;  // change the head so that it can be the first_head
        new_Node.add(null);   //to solve the lastNode[i+1]
         i = 0;
```

in this piece Why get this things..  the code can't run..
  //Line 33 rror: cannot find symbol: variable get*

```
 while(head!=null){
                new_Node.get[i].next=new_Node.get[i+1];
                //Line 33 rror: cannot find symbol: variable get*
```

the finally code

```
    if(head.random!=null){
            int id = old_Node.get[head.random];
            //find the randomNode's number 
            new_Node.get[i].random =new_Node.get[id];

        }
        head=head.next;
        i++;
    }
    return new_Node.get[0];
}
```

}

Can anyone help me . i think this code is not really well must have someBug

First add a Map and a List

then put the number and Node to the map

then new a List to store the Node

Comment: You can only use `[]` with an array. Do you mean `new_Node.get(i)`?

Comment: There is no array called `get` and `[]` is **only** for arrays.

Comment: sorry so much ,i ;m watch the API ,i will see it carefully

Comment: Because i am watch. . an.answer using
C so after i change the（） the answer is stillnot true please helpme thanks